# SplashScreen is this the correct approach?

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-activity

Please note the following seems to work ok. I just need opinions if this is the correct logic or If I can do anything that would work better

So this is my 1st time ever using a splash-screen. works as intended so far (or so I think)  I just need some opinions if the logic I use is good or if I can improve this.  so basically in the background I have a class called Reader (Async task) where it reads from 7 different links (as you will see it being called 7 times) 
and populate my database. what I want my splashscreen to do is populate that database and then run mainActivity. (also have the screen up long enough just to show the sponsor if any)

so I came up with this. I know I cant have my async task non-static but then I could not have variable change. (isAsyncCompleted) Seen this method from this site.

```
public class SplashActicity extends AppCompatActivity {
boolean isHandlerCompleted, isAsyncCompleted = false;

private static int SPLASH_SCREEN_TIME_OUT = 1000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_acticity);

     MyTask myTask = new MyTask();
     myTask.execute();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            isHandlerCompleted = true;
            if (isHandlerCompleted && isAsyncCompleted) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActicity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }, SPLASH_SCREEN_TIME_OUT);


}

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        Reader fromthepast = new Reader(getApplicationContext(), "http://www.lemesosblog.com/index.php?option=com_obrss&task=feed&id=7%3Alemesos-apo-to-parelthon&format=feed", "fromthepast");
        Reader international = new Reader(getApplicationContext(), "http://www.lemesosblog.com/index.php?option=com_obrss&task=feed&id=9%3Alemesos-diethni&format=feed", "international");
        Reader latestNews = new Reader(getApplicationContext(), "http://lemesosblog.com/index.php?option=com_obrss&task=feed&id=3%253Alemesos-teleftea-nea&format=feed&fbclid=IwAR1VeGagGZD_M_ACBx8tAA38afhVallFc5LG6U58HYCq8iLJFNLKsaXtVAI", "latestNews");
        Reader health = new Reader(getApplicationContext(), "http://www.lemesosblog.com/index.php?option=com_obrss&task=feed&id=6:lemesos-ygeia&format=feed", "health");
        Reader technology = new Reader(getApplicationContext(), "http://www.lemesosblog.com/index.php?option=com_obrss&task=feed&id=5%3Alemesos-tech&format=feed", "technology");
        Reader economy = new Reader(getApplicationContext(), "http://www.lemesosblog.com/index.php?option=com_obrss&task=feed&id=4:lemesos-oikonomia&format=feed", "economy");
        Reader tepak = new Reader(getApplicationContext(), "http://www.lemesosblog.com/index.php?option=com_obrss&task=feed&id=8:lemesos-tepak&format=feed", "tepak");
        economy.execute();
        health.execute();
        fromthepast.execute();
        international.execute();
        latestNews.execute();
        technology.execute();
        tepak.execute();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        isAsyncCompleted = true;
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what happens if your handler completes before your async is completed?

Answer (score 0):

In your case if handler completes execution before your async is completed then your condition will be invalid and your code will not be executed. IF there isn't any specific requirement to block next activity till specified timeout, You should move your code inside `handler` to `onPostExecute()`

Comment: So by moving the handler in onPostExecute it will still do what I need it to do?
Call the 7 Async task that I have, and continue to next activity when loading is finished? and in case that loading is shorter than 3 seconds wait for that 3secodns to pass?

Just wondering if my thought process was put in to code.